# Provide Custom Select on ModelForm

Tags: django-forms

I am trying to create a custom drop down select for a modelForm.  Right now the model form just shows all the Units with no hierarchy.  I would like the form to have a select box like parent / child ordered by college then by their departments under them:

```
<select>
<option value="10000">COLLEGE A</option>
<option value="10001">    DEPT A</option>
<option value="10002">    DEPT B</option>
<option value="20000">COLLEGE B</option>
<option value="20001">    DEPT C</option>
.....
</select>
```

I have a model of all "units" on our campus.  If the parent is None then it is a college.  Each department points to a college.

```
class Units(models.Model):
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.parent:
            return self.parent.unit_name + ': ' + self.unit_name
        else:
            return self.unit_name
```

I abstracted my User class as follows so all my users can have an associated unit

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    associated_unit = models.ForeignKey(Units)
    ...........
```

On the screen that edits the user I want the drop down associated_unit box to list it hierarchy as above and not so linear.  This is what I got to date for the form to list only "enabled" units.

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'is_active', 'associated_unit')

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(UserForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.fields['associated_unit'].queryset = Units.objects.filter(enabled=True).order_by('parent__unit_name', 'unit_name')
```

How do I go about creating a custom select drop down as detailed above?  Any help is appreciated.  Tired of experimenting and researching :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the last line to: **self.fields['associated_unit'].choices = my_list**.  Seems to save now :D

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'is_active', 'associated_unit')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        my_list = []

        colleges = Units.objects.filter(parent=None, enabled=True).order_by('unit_name')
        for college in colleges:
            my_list.append((college.id, college.unit_name))

            departments = Units.objects.filter(parent=college.id, enabled=True).order_by('unit_name')
            for department in departments:
                my_list.append((department.id,  "   =>   " + department.unit_name))

        self.fields['associated_unit'].choices = my_list
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work.  Might not be the best solution but it does work.  Can not get white spaces to show in select box however for college / department name.

Used a > instead.

```
from users.models import Profile
from units.models import Units
from django.forms import ModelForm, ChoiceField


class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'is_active', 'associated_unit')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        my_list = []

        colleges = Units.objects.filter(parent=None, enabled=True).order_by('unit_name')
        for college in colleges:
            my_list.append((college.id, college.unit_name))

            departments = Units.objects.filter(parent=college.id, enabled=True).order_by('unit_name')
            for department in departments:
                my_list.append((department.id,  "   =>   " + department.unit_name))

        self.fields['associated_unit'] = ChoiceField(choices=my_list)
```

Comment: Not out of the woods yet.  Now I get this error when I save the form.  Back to the drawing board.

Cannot assign "'12006'": "Profile.associated_unit" must be a "Units" instance.